# How to plot a scatter plot over a line plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

My problem is that I need to plot (in the same figure) a scatter plot and also A LOT of lines, but the scatter plot ALWAYS gets to be in the back of the figure so the lines always covers them.

Is there a way to plot the scatter plot above the lines so it can be seen ?

I've tried with the basic things like the order in which I make the plots but I always get the same.

Comment: have you tried using the `alpha` parameter to make the line more transparent? A use case like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40766909/suggestions-to-plot-overlapping-lines-in-matplotlib)?

Comment: That worked! Thanks a lot!, you should repost this as an answer so I can tick you.

Comment: I'm actually going to mark this as a duplicate. Here on StackOverflow we try to avoid the same answers to the same question best we can :) Even though yours is not the *same* question. It was solved by the same answer on a very similar question